# M2 How to use URL parameter passing to select store view

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-view, stores, store-switcher

We are setting multi language with different store view. In the launching page there are links to redirect to different store views.

However the **`__store=storeview`** parameter seems cannot write to cookie so after jumping several pages will switch to default store view.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: did you get your solution?

Answer (score 2):

You missing one underscore in the parameter name. It should be `___store={storeview_code}`

Also, all state modifications should happen using POST request. Otherwise, the page might be cached by varnish or built-in cache.

Comment: Sorry for typo in our program we correctly put 3 underscore ___store={storeview_code}. Also we have tried your suggestion of using POST request but seems cannot resolve the problem. I have think of cache  issue, however when we made change on front page or blocks the changes can show so not likely is cached page